# change the format of date in Joomla! 2.5 article

Tags: date, joomla, styles, joomla2.5

I'm trying to change the format of the "article publishing date" on Joomla! 2.5 based webpage. I've made some changes in code based on an article: 
http://magazine.joomla.org/topics/item/455-How-to-put-more-love-into-your-Joomla-dates?tmpl=component&print=1 but it doesnt work for 2.5 version. 
Please Help!

Comment: can't really help if you don't provide the code changes you have made and if you're ok with it, providing the url to your website.

Comment: oryginal: .../views/article/default.php

Comment: no i mean the changes YOU have made ;)

Comment: ;) http://wklej.to/RC5py

Comment: oh you mean the format of the date, not the style. was confused

Comment: Sadly, in 2.5 currently you can't alter both the date format and the 'Created on' text, just one or the other. Saving resets the other one.

Comment: WAIT - no, you simply have to save TWO alterations to the system. I kept updating the same one :-)

Answer (score 7):

Joomla! 2.5 uses language keys to retrieve date formats - you can override these using the Language Manager.

Select `Extensions`->`Language Manager`->`Overrides` then you can create a new version of the standard date strings.

The standard date keys and their format strings are:

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="y-m-d"
```

The format used most commonly by `com_content` is the `DATE_FORMAT_LC2`, so if you create an override for that you will change how your article dates are formatted.

The format strings are [standard PHP date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).